# Service Layer in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a small application in Spring and Spring Data JPA.
I need serval layer. I don't know if I'm doing well.

Here is an example:
**POJO**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long Id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private int price;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "Id=" + Id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    Product findByName(String name);
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    Product getProductById(String productId);
    void addProduct(Product product);
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public interface ProductService  {

    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    Product getProductById(String productId);
    void addProduct(Product product);
}
```

**REPOSITORY IMPLEMENTATION**

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.getAllProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(String productId) {
        return productRepository.getProductById(productId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.addProduct(product);

    }

}
```

It is a good?
Unless How create communication with database in Spring?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review, not on Stackoverflow

Comment: Independent of the question being off topic: It is not really clear what your question is. What are your goals you want to achieve by creating a layered architecture?

Answer (score 1):

In the sources folder, you create a resource file **src/main/resources/application.properties**
and mention the below properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```